# Bind image source dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

I want to create a function to my WP8 application which tells the user if GPS signal is initalizing, ready etc. I want to do that with a small picture, questionmark if still searching, X if there is no data, and a check mark if OK. I am working with MVVM Light.

Here is what I have so far:

In my View, I have these lines:

```
...
DataContext="{Binding Signal, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
...
<Image Source="{Binding Signalstrength.Imageuri, Converter={StaticResource SignalstatusConverter}}" Width="38" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" />
```

I have created a converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string path = System.Convert.ToString(value);

        if (App.Geolocator != null)
        {
            switch (App.Geolocator.LocationStatus)
            {
                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionStatus.Disabled:
                    path = "/Assets/close.png";
                    break;
                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionStatus.Initializing:
                    path = "/Assets/questionmark.png";
                    break;
                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionStatus.NoData:
                    path = "/Assets/close.png";
                    break;
                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionStatus.NotAvailable:
                    path = "/Assets/close.png";
                    break;
                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionStatus.NotInitialized:
                    path = "/Assets/questionmark.png";
                    break;
                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionStatus.Ready:
                    path = "/Assets/check.png";
                    break;
                default:
                    path = "/Assets/close.png";
                    break;
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            path = "/Assets/questionmark.png";
        }

        return path;
    }
```

In the ViewModel class:

```
public class SignalViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Signalstrength _signalstrength;        

    public Signalstrength Signalstrength
    {
        get { return _signalstrength; }
        set 
        {
            _signalstrength = value;
            Set("Signalstrength", ref _signalstrength, value);
        }
    }
    public SignalViewModel()
    {
            _signalstrength = new Signalstrength
            {
                Imageuri = "/Assets/questionmark.png",
                State = "initializing"
            };

    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Signalstrength : ObservableObject
    {
        private string _state;
        private string _imageuri;        

        public string State
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set 
            {
                _state = value;
                Set("State", ref _state, value);
            }
        }

        public string Imageuri
        {
            get { return _imageuri; }
            set
            {
                _imageuri = value;
                Set("Imageuri", ref _imageuri, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the application, it works fine, but just once. If I start the Geolocator in my MainPage, I see that it found my position, so the Status must be OK, but the image is still the questionmark image, not the checkmark.

What am I missing? How can I make to refresh the image? And finally, the approach I tried to implement this meets with the MVVM requirements?

**EDIT:**
I don't know if that could be a problem, but I have 3 ViewModels: MainViewModel, WorkoutViewModel and SignalViewModel. In my MainPage, I display these like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <views:WorkoutView IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <views:SignalstrengthView IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        </Grid>
```

I'd set the DataContext up in their Views.
The MainViewModel is for the MainPage, I use it for the Applicationbar. If the user clicks on the AppbarButton, I turn on the GPS. So that code is in the MainViewModel, but the items to display these changes are in the SignalViewModel. Could this be a problem?

**EDIT2:**
It seems the Geolocator runs in a background thread, because of this I can't update the UI.

Comment: Looks like you're missing some INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: I think that is automatically called by the Set(), if needed.

Comment: I think it calls it on the change to Signalstrength, not it's sub properties.  Because, your code look correct to me.  I don't have my phone with me atm to really test it out.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware I tried to call RaisePropertyChanged manually, and still nothing happens.

Comment: You do not need a converter, just move the converter logic to the view model constructor.

Comment: @Faisal I've tried it, still not working.

Comment: It not good according to MVVM requirements you should use Geolocator.StatusChanged event but you will need to have the Geolocator in the SignalViewModel and subscribe to StatusChanged.

Answer (score 0):

This is your new model

```
public class Signalstrength : ObservableObject
    {
        private PositionStatus _state;      

        public PositionStatus State
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set 
            {
                _state = value;
                Set("State", ref _state, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the constructor of the view model

```
_signalstrength = new Signalstrength
            {
                State = Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionStatus.Disabled
            };
```

This is the view

```
...
DataContext="{Binding Signal, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
...
<Image Source="{Binding Signalstrength.State, Converter={StaticResource SignalstatusConverter}}" Width="38" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Comment: Put a break point in the else branch of the converter and one on the switch statement, maybe remove the else branch. Make sure you initialize the Geolocator in App.xaml.cs if it is null it will go the else branch. It should look like public Geolocator Geolocator = new Geolocator();

Comment: The program works correctly there when I run the first time. The problem is when I start acquiring my position, the program doesn't even enters to the Converter code.